# Microsoft Extensibility Framework - MEF CompositionContainer

Tags: c#, mef

I'm in the process of building a Windows Service that implements MEF.  The idea is that the service should manage sub-components and be pluggable, where any number of new components can be introduced at runtime without having to go through a full service recompile and deploy scenario.  The components should be pluggable, meaning that as soon as I drop an output assembly into a designated folder on disc, the Windows Service should say "Hey, here's a new component to run..." and just do it's thing.  That's the power of MEF.  Very cool stuff so far.

I understand the concept of creating an AggregateCatalog and a CompositionContainer to import all available sub-components (assemblies).  This is all good, and it works as expected when the Windows Service is intially started up.  However, I'm eventually going to be introducing new components at runtime, so at some point I'm going to need the CompositionContainer to recognize any new output assemblies that are added.

My concern with the following is any implications on performance.  Is it safe / efficient to put the CompositionContainer logic into a loop such as the following:

```
        [ImportMany(AllowRecomposition = true)]
        private IEnumerable<Lazy<IMySubComponentTask, IDictionary<string, object>>>                        
        MySubComponentTasks { get; set; }

        while (true)
        {
          //Create a general aggregate catalog
          var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();

          //Adds all the parts found in the same assembly as the Program class
          catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(MySubComponentTaskFactory).Assembly));

          //Create a new directory catalog
          var directoryCatalog = new DirectoryCatalog(@".\Extensions");

          //Add the DLLs in the directory to the aggregate catalog
          catalog.Catalogs.Add(directoryCatalog);

          //Create the current composition container to create the parts
          var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

          //Fill the imports of this object
          try
          {
            container.ComposeParts(this);
          }
          catch (CompositionException compositionException)
          {
            Console.WriteLine(compositionException.ToString());
          }
       }
```

Any feedback or input is appreciated.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I would not put the catalog instantiation into a loop. However, maybe a `System.Timers.Timer` or `System.Threading.Timer` to periodically check the plugin directory - whichever best suits your need.

Since your ImportMany allows recomposition you should be able to add new compositions at runtime:

```
Timer checkPlugin = new Timer();

//set CheckForPlugins as a timer callback or action
void CheckForPlugins()
{
    // add plugins catalog if found in directory
}
```

I found some additional information: [Recomposition and constructors](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gblock/archive/2009/03/21/recomposition-and-constructors.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I was probably going to head down that path.  Here's another thing, which I didn't mention above for brevity.  For each sub-component that the CompositionContainer discovers during each timed lookup, I'm going to kick the sub-component job off into a separate thread.  To manage the amount of threads that are newed up, I'm going to have to check if there's a thread already running a sub-component job that was discovered during a previous timed lookup. What is your experience using threads and just how many threads is too much?  At some point, I may have 15+ sub-components for this thing

Comment: @michael: The max number of threads depends on CPU and core architecture. I would reference the Task Parallel Library to manage component threading.

Answer (score 0):

Creating CompositionContainers should be cheap.  Creating catalogs is not so cheap because the assemblies have to be inspected to find MEF parts.  So you should create your catalog outside of the loop if possible.